# Does firebase-simple-login persistance work with cordova/android hybrid app?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebasesimplelogin

I am trying to change my app over to use firebase-simple-login and use within a hybrid mobile app using cordova/ionic.  I am having an issue with persistance.   I have looked at the firebase-simple-login.js code and it appears that the library is dependent upon BOTH cookies and localStorage being available:

```
fb.simplelogin.SessionStore_.prototype.get = function() {
    if (hasLocalStorage) {
        try {
            var a = goog.net.cookies.get(encryptionStorageKey),
                d = localStorage.getItem(sessionPersistentStorageKey);
            if (a && d)  return fb.simplelogin.util.json.parse(sjcl.decrypt(a, fb.simplelogin.util.json.parse(d)))
        } catch (e) {
        }
        return null
    }
};
```

Debugging this, I see that d is returned successfully but when running as a native install using cordova on android, a is not set but d is.  So,  persistence is never successful.

FYI,  I have InAppBrowser plugin installed and bez4pieci.cookies installed.

Is the problem that I "should" be able to get cookie to resolve on when running natively?  It currently does not.  At least in a way that firebase expects.

Comment: There is [a blog post and sample github repo on this topic](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-25-ionic-simple-login.html). So yes, it works.

Comment: Kato, a blog post that shows it orking on an iOS emulator does not demonstrate that it will work on an android device.  I had already read the post.